# Can't create mixin for @font-face in VisualStudio 13 with web-essentials

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, less, font-face, web-essentials

Hi I use VisualStudio13 with web-essentials. 
I want to create a less mixin for font-face.

I get a green curly under the `@font-face` and it says `Unexcpected '@' block  style rule`. It cannot be compiled cause of that...

```
.fontFace(@flamaPath, "Flama-Basic")

.fontFace(@basePath, @fontName) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: '@{fontName}';
        src: url('@{basePath}/@{fontName}.eot');
        src: url('@{basePath}/@{fontName}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('@{basePath}/@{fontName}.woff') format('woff');
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only a missing semicolon:

```
.fontFace(@flamaPath, "Flama-Basic"); // <- Here
```

Of course, `@flamaPath` must be defined.

Comment: the compiler from visual studio (web-essentials) still throws some errors, even more then before...

Comment: @NinjaOnSafari I've reviewed it, and the problem was much simpler. I've tested it carefully, and it was a missign semicolon.